# How to use HTML conditional statements with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM web app that uses some features not available prior to IE 10. So while I know JQM supports earlier browsers, I want to alert my users that my app does not.

I put the following as the first lines inside the `<body>` tag in my index.html file:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<div class="browsehappy">
    You are using an <span class="bold">outdated</span> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
</div>
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm wondering now if JQM's page AJAX system is preventing this from working properly.

Example: http://jsbin.com/oGIRoCE/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done with JQM.